# How to take a full page screenshot in Mac OS Safari?

Tags: macos, safari-extensions, productivity

I'm looking for a [Safari Extension](https://extensions.apple.com) that can take **full page** screenshots. I am aware there are various extensions, but haven't found any that would take full page images.

Comment: I couldn't get Awesome Screenshot to work with all websites, but I've used [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) and [Paparazzi](http://derailer.org/paparazzi/).

Comment: The other question covers the same end result functionality, but the accepted answer is not a Safari Extension, so unless tillinberlin really doesn't need an extension, this is fine as a related question and not a duplicate.

Comment: I understand "possible duplicate" but since other questions and other apps weren't really featuring *full page* I just had to ask…

Comment: Paparazzi! very good, versatile, free.                 http://derailer.org/paparazzi/

Comment: @tillinberlin Would you be amenable to removing the solved check mark from the answer that is causing malware/security concerns? You don't have to, but if the tool isn't preferred - another option or none might be better for others.

Comment: Not sure when it was added, but as of at least October 5, 2020 extensions are no longer necessary to create full page screenshots. See this answer for details no how to do it: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/342563/7828

Comment: Google links here first, but [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30637/saving-a-safari-page-as-a-png-image/418265#418265) has better / more recent answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<s>Maybe</s> **Don't** give http://awesomescreenshot.com/ a try, **see disclaimer below. There are better options available, see other answers to this question.** Awesome Screenshot is a browser plugin that can capture

- the full site
- the visible part *or*
- a selection of the site.

It also allows for basic annotation of the screenshot as well as downloading it or saving it on the web for access by URL. Available as extension to Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

**DISCLAIMER: there are [strong indications](https://mig5.net/content/awesome-screenshot-and-niki-bot) that Awesome Screenshot sends information about your browser history to third party servers. I would *not* recommend this after all. It also has a history of integrating [adware](http://www.thesafemac.com/screenshot-extension-injects-ads/) in it's extension and then [apologizing for it afterwards](https://twitter.com/awe_screenshot/status/495350768128368640).**

Comment: Warning: "Awesome Screenshot" [contains adware](http://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?p=24997&sid=f12571d12ee7752872394b00e337f8ee).

Comment: Awesome screenshot can havoc your life because of adware, unnecessary ads, slow down you browser and much more. 3rd answer below is best answer. No plugin is needed.

Comment: Extension is garbage chrome adware, original question was for a safari extension.

Comment: @BadPirate At the time the question was asked there was a Safari extension available.

Comment: @greenforest -- Think you should pull the answer as it's no longer correct and leads users to a website that seems to be adware / malware driven.  Second answer provide (just below this one) is a great solution, answers the question specifically, and provides better screenshots anyway.  Nothing personal, but the correct answer for the question should be the best one.

Comment: @BadPirate Changed the answer but can't remove the checkmark. Hope tillinberlin will change.

Comment: If you can't delete the answer due to the checkmark, we can do it for you if you want.

Comment: How is the extension these days? Just installed it and din't noticed anything suspicious about it.

Answer (score 48):

No plugins or anything needed - latest Safari (7, not sure from which version this works) can save to PDF. *File -> Export as PDF...* and you get entire page, images and all. And it's a lovely hi-res PDF.

Comment: I don't know if it's Bootstrap or not, but my PDF is black and white with minimal styling.

Comment: The only thing to consider is that the PDF will have page breaks. If you need one, continuous, unbroken flow, then PDF is not the right choice.

Comment: I think this actually just Prints to PDF. Not really a true full-page screen-capture-to-pdf.

Comment: Just exports the current view to PDF, not the whole page.

Comment: It does not export a WYSISYG image of the page. Good only for so many purposes, unacceptable for a lot more.

Comment: Well, I got an ugly version of my page in pdf. CSS totally broken.

Comment: exports badly formatted view. not recommended!

Comment: To be clear, websites can *intentionally* have different designs for print, vs. for web browsers — this question is (at least from my perspective) about capturing the latter.

Comment: This doesn't generate a full-page screenshot… It's just a poor PDF print of the page. Pretty difficult, if not impossible, to have what you actually see (plus what you don't see unless you scroll) on screen in the generated PDF. This answer is irrelevant.

Comment: With Safari 14 this works like a charm. It's different from `Print > Save as PDF`! `Print` will break it down into pages and add margins but `File > Export as PDF` will export it as is.

Answer (score 35):

[Paparazzi!](http://derailer.org/paparazzi/) is great for full page screenshots. It is not a Safari Extension, yet it has a very nice feature that enables you to launch it from Safari.

Type `paparazzi:` in the address bar before the URL, it will launch the application with specified URL. Here is the list of URL format that Paparazzi! uses: http://derailer.org/paparazzi/urlformat

Comment: Great! Works for very long page that Chrome extension cannot handle!

Comment: The best screenshot capturer for Mac. Forget browser extensions. Paparazzi is awesome.

Comment: Agreed. This tool really is great. Especially combined with the ability to interact with the web view and add delays and whatnot. Thanks @mkubilayk!

Comment: "if you turn on the `Develop` menu for Safari, you should be able to go from `Safari > Develop > Open With > Paparazzi`", from here: https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/3srndw/is_there_a_working_safariextension_for/cx0wtay

Comment: Cannot handle pages that requires you to login.

Comment: @sul4bh You can use the "Interact with Web View" feature to login, via using either pointer icon at the bottom left or View menu.

Comment: Paparazzi! is great. Also, as others found out, extensions are far from a good choice for privacy.

Comment: Hum, problems with Paparazzi!: cannot capture menus for exemple… Plus, it's not exactly screenshots of what you see in Safari. It's a great tool, but, doesn't really fit all needs. Sorry that for now, using Awesome + Chrome is the last options (since it seems that Awesome is not available for Safari anymore)

Answer (score 4):

Safari can do this out of the box: the key is that you need to adjust the page size when printing to PDF.

1. Load the website
2. File -> Print...
3. Under the "Paper Size" pop-up, select "Manage Custom Sizes"
4. Create a new paper size that fits the entire webpage (eg, 8.5in x 30in).
5. Use the PDF pop-up to "Save as PDF..."

The downside to this approach is that if the site has different screen and print styles, you can only get a PDF of the print style.

Comment: Thanks for this! 7 years later this is still very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any Safari Extensions which can do this, but [Skitch](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch/id425955336?mt=12) can also do this.

Comment: Skitch 1.x had a "snap Safari" functionality that was wonderful for making an image of the entire Safari canvas without needing to manually scroll the window down from the top to the bottom. That function was removed from Skitch 2.0 and is still absent in the current version on the App Store :(

Comment: Skitch marks up a web page; Evernote copies them.

Answer (score 1):

[Evernote Web Clipper](https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.evernote.safari.clipper-Q79WDW8YH9), a Safari extension, clips Full Screen or Selection. To a web notebook, yes, but that syncs to Evernote on your computer just about instantly, manually, or set a timed sync.

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, even though it recommends a third-party product, which is not what the user asked for. Go to evernote.com or the App Store and download the app. The clipper is installed with it. Not only does it save web pages as one, long contiguous image, you can actually edit the page like it was a Word document or something. The fonts stay the same, the page reflows like it was Dreamweaver or the like. I don't know why they made the effort, but they did, and it works great.

Comment: How do you do this? I can't get the Clipper to take a screenshot of the entire page. It will *save* the page into Evernote, but what results is not an exportable image, and the "screenshot" function only captures the visible screen, or some subset thereof.

Answer (score 1):

CHROME> try extension called full screen capture. I found it to be quick and captures very long htmls pages as pngs. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: It's helpful if you provide links to the App/Extension that you are referencing.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  OP is looking for a Safari extension not Chrome.  - From Review

Comment: Not available for Safari. If you have Chrome, the link is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl

Comment: How unhelpful, @NileshParmar. No, most ‘normal people’ (not developers, not designers) don't have multiple browsers on their machine; nor *should* they.

Comment: Of additional note to scrollers, and devs/designers who *do* have Chrome additionally installed, though — Chrome [now has this built-in](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#screenshots) (Chrome 59+), so no extension is required.

Comment: nice plugin. it does not work for safari, but at least it helped me do my job. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Safari, click Save As... on the File menu; then, click Save to create a PDF of the web page on the Desktop. Open the PDF in Preview. Click Export As... on the File menu. Choose an image format, and then click Save.

For a complete listing of all screenshot-capture command available in the Finder: support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361

By the way, on Mac OS X 10.11.x, you can set a system preference to hide the menu bar, just like the dock.

Answer (score -2):

Try [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html). It is not a Safari extension, but it is always available if you choose for it to be.  It will amaze -- and it's free.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different! When presenting software as a solution, please provide a link to the program in question. It makes for a better answer and will be easier to upvote. ;)

Comment: Jing doesn't take full page screenshots.

Answer (score -3):

1. Open that website
2. Go to **File** → **Save as** from the menu bar
3. Save it on your desktop

You will then have your webpage screenshot on your desktop

Comment: No, you'll have a web archive of the page, or the page source code, neither of which are a screenshot?

Answer (score -5):

To get a png of an open window—including Safari webpage:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

...which makes a crosshair appear...then...
press <kbd>Space</kbd>
...turning the crosshair into a camera icon. Use this to click on the window/webpage you want to screenshot. It includes the drop shadow with transparency.

Comment: No use if the web page scrolls though.

Comment: Can't have everything! Stitch it together with Photoshop.

Comment: saves only the visible part of the page, but at least it's completely built-in.  I think you can turn off the drop-shadow with TinkerTool - don't quote me on that.

Comment: As noted in the other answers though, you can have everything :)

Comment: See my revised answer

Comment: I wonder if there is an app that can auto-stitch together screenshots that overlap slightly. Safari is not the only browser that doesn’t have an extension for full-page screenshot generation. (Also: MS Edge and the browser on Linux distro Elementary)